# Django project, 2 apps, multiple logins

Tags: django

I'm deploying a simple django project that will have a few subtleties. I will be using several apps with similar functionality, and they will be "folders" under the same domain, e.g., `domain.com/app1` and `domain.com/app2`. etc.

The thing is, i'd like for app1 and app2 to have different logins. A logged-in user for app1 may or may not be a user for app2.

I've thought of a few ways to do this:

1. Separate projects
2. Groups (<del>possibly extend `login_required`</del> `user_passes_test` decorator, so that only members of `app1` group can get to `app1` edit views.)
3. ???
4. Profit!

<del>So far, #2 seems best for me, since the apps will be pretty simple (perhaps only one model per app).</del>

EDIT: I guess I could just use a `user_passes_test` instead of `login_required`

Am I missing something? Is there a better way?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: `user_passes_test` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer for me is the awesome `permission_required` decorator.
This is nice, since superusers have all permissions.

My edit function will look something like this:

```
@login_required()
@permission_required('app1.add_vorpalbunny', raise_exception=True)
def add_vorpal_bunny(request, *args, **kwargs):
    #do view code ....
```